# Configuring Swagger with Play/Java-framework-2.5

Tags: java, playframework, swagger-ui, playframework-2.5, swagger-play2

I am trying to configure [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) with my Play-2.5 project.

I followed this [tutorial](http://swagger.io/playing-with-swagger-using-swagger-and-swagger-ui-with-the-play-framework/) and it worked, but only for the older version of Play and not working with Play-2.5. As the project has migrated into Play-2.5, we had to remove the swagger configuration.

Firstly, the issue seemed to be with static controller vs non static controller in Play-2.5, but I ended up with proving myself wrong.
I am facing this error

```
      type ApiHelpController is not a member of package controllers 
      GET         /api-docs                controllers.ApiHelpController.getResources
```

If any one knows any link for Swagger configuration with Play-2.5 for **Java**, please guide.

PS: there are tutorials available for Scala not for **java**.

Comment: Actually your question is about 'a way to integrate Swagger with Play-2.5'. Basically, it is not a problem whether you are doing a Java project or Scala project unless if there's a problem with annotator libraries .

Comment: I am facing the same problem, :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this repo:

https://github.com/CreditCardsCom/swagger-play

I created this as a temporary workaround until we get support for Play 2.5 in the official swagger-play repo.

Comment: this for scala not java, Do you have for  java play.?

Comment: It _is_ for Java play. I'm currently using it with Java, not scala.

Comment: Could you guide how to integrate step by step , thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have only used the [Play-Swagger project from Zalando](https://github.com/zalando/play-swagger). There is a lot of documentation and the repo is kept up-to-date.

If you want a quick start you can take a look at their [Activator Template](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/play-swagger-service) - just run it and you will get the Swagger generated documentation (Swagger UI is already included). From there you can start tweaking it (look for the `conf/echo.yaml` file).

Comment: I have seen this before but again this all help out there for older versions and for Scala. I am looking for java with play 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the com.wordnik swagger-play2(What your tutorial is using as a library) breaks with Play 2.4 and up.
You can try [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play/tree/master/play-2.4/swagger-play2) which uses a different one (io.swagger). I have used this and it works well with 2.4. But it also breaks with 2.5.